# Access PHP session variable at any time with a jQuery AJAX request?

Tags: php, ajax, variables, jquery

I need to access PHP session variable at any time with a jQuery AJAX request? Is this possible?

What I'm doing, from a "main.html" is making an jQuery AJAX POST request to an external php file "php/upload.php." This script will take 30 minutes or so to run, and while it's running, it is constantly updating a session variable "$_SESSION['var']". I'd like to be able to check the value of this session variable at any time from my "main.html" page. Is that possible using jQuery (or another way)?

I'll be using this session variable to report back how close to completion the "php/upload.php" is to finishing.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm just a little curious.  What are you doing that's going to take 30 minutes to run?

Answer (score 2):

write a new PHP-file (check.php) with the Contents:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["var"];
?>
```

And request it with AJAX. The File only contents the Variable. If you want ho have it mor Flexible look up [json](http://json.org) (JavaScriptObjecktNotification)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the session is only saved at the end of the script execution. So any changes you make in `upload.php` won't be reflected until the script has ended. You would be better storing the data you need in memcache or even just a file. If you made the file readable by the web server then you could just poll it.

You might however want to consider redesigning the system. A long running PHP script is never usually a good idea.

Comment: oh hmm that could be a problem then

Answer (score 1):

If you're ajaxing something that will take 30 minutes to respond then your connection is gonna timeout and you aren't going to get anything. Perhaps look into using something like comet, which will allow you to open up a long-polling connection and push data from the server to the client. Maybe this will help: [How to implement COMET with PHP](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start)

Comment: it's not timing out, I just have to wait a while

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what you are saying.  Try doing:

```
var timer=setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery.get('yourscript.php',{getVar:sessionVar},function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
},1000);
```

Then clear your time when you are done.
And in your PHP file:

```
if(isset($_GET['getVar'] && $_GET['getVar']=='sessionVar')
    exit($_SESSION['var']);
```

Comment: is 'yourscript.php' a different php file than the 'php/upload.php' I mentioned?

Comment: I would probably do it a different file.  But that is just me.  You could definitely throw in the code to your upload.php but if something is uploading, it may possibly slow down the execution of the same code.  Plus the smaller the file size it has to search through, the faster it will return the result.